# Nodejs with express not listening/catching webhooks

Tags: node.js, express, webhooks

I'm trying to catch a json webhooks using Nodejs and Express the code runs fine and i can run npm start but it doesn't work.
This is the code im running on the webserver. Any idea on where im making mistakes?

Thanks

```
var express = require('express');
app = express()
port = 3000;

app.use = (express.json());
app.use = (express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
    }))

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    var prod = req.body
    console.log(req.body)

    if (prod.total > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < prod.total; i++ ){
        var sku = body.productos[i].codigo_var;
        var stock = body.productos[i].stock;
        var precio = body.productos[i].precios[0].precio;

        var actualizar = {
            sku,
            stock,
            precio
            }
        console.log(actualizar)
        }

var server = app.listen(port, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log('App en http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
```

Comment: define "doesn't work". Are there errors? Or did you not get the parameter you want? Or did the request reach the nodejs app? Ask good questions so you can get proper answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some closing brackets for the POST route.

You will also need to run `npm i body-parser` since express no longer has that functionality built in.

Finally I noticed that the `body` variable isn't declared anywhere so I updated to `prod` which has the req.body data.

I was able to get the following code to run locally and iterate through the json data I sent.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app = express()
port = 3000;

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var prod = req.body

  if (prod.total > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < prod.total; i++ ) {
      var sku = prod.productos[i].codigo_var;
      var stock = prod.productos[i].stock;
      var precio = prod.productos[i].precios[0].precio;

      var actualizar = {
        sku,
        stock,
        precio,
      }
      console.log(actualizar)
      return res.send(actualizar)
    }
  // Missing brackets
  }
});

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('App en http://%s:%s', host, port)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I closed it correctly but it doesn't work anyways

Comment: My answer should work now. I updated it with more information as well as additional things I found when setting it up to run locally.